# one to may relationship, Display all post along with there users

Tags: laravel

//Post table
user()

```
`belongsTo(User::class);`
```

//user table
posts()

```
hasMany(post::class);
```

//I want to get all the post available in the DB, Display along with the users associated with the post.

Answer (score 1):

Use foreign key and primary key in relationships to get the results.

In Post

```
 public function user()
 {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User','users_id','users_id') //first parameter-foreign key,second parameter-local key
 }
```

In User

```
 public function posts()
 {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Post','users_id','users_id')
 }
```

Now get all the posts using

```
 $posts = Post::get();
 return view('your-view')->with('posts',$posts);
```

You can retrieve user information in view using

```
 @foreach($posts as $post)  
   $user = $post->user->name;
 @endforeach
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks got the concept now

Answer (score 0):

Guessing your relations look like this:

User:

```
 public function posts()
 {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
 }
```

Post:

```
 public function user()
 {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User')
 }
```

You could get all the posts in your controller, like this:

```
$posts = Post::get();
return view('your view', $posts);
```

And in your blade, to display posts and their users, do it like this:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
   $post->user->name
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks got the concept now

Comment: If this was a solution that you were looking for, mark it as an answer, so future users with the same problems can find this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$posts = Post::with('user')->get();
```